# JavaScript object with couple of parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

### The goal

I want to create a function which have couples of parameters like that:

```
MyObject.calculateResponsiveHeights({
    containers: {
        ".content",
        ".sidebar"
    },
    spacing: {
        125, // This will be attributed to ".content"
        240 // This will be attributed to ".sidebar"
    }
});
```

### The problem

I do not how I can do this.

### What I have now (the function implementation — just to be aware of the situation)

```
function calculateResponsiveMeasures() {
    var containerContentResponsiveHeight = $(window).height() - 185,
        sidebarProductsSummaryResponsiveHeight = $(window).height() - 255;

    containerContentResponsiveHeight = containerContentResponsiveHeight + "px";
    sidebarProductsSummaryResponsiveHeight = sidebarProductsSummaryResponsiveHeight + "px";

    $(".container-content").css("height", containerContentResponsiveHeight);
    $(".products-summary").css("height", sidebarProductsSummaryResponsiveHeight);
}
```

Yeah, that's disgusting, huh?

### Observations

I'm not asking to improve my code, nor say whether it is better or worse way to do — I just want to better organize my function.

Cheers!

Comment: "Better organize my function" means "improving your code"

Comment: Where is the call to `MyObject.calculateResponsiveHeights` ?

Comment: @JuanMendes Of course I want to improve my code organizing him — but I'm not asking to you to do this for me. And about the call: There is not a call — was just an illustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to create an *array*: `[1, 2, 3]`.

However, you should use a single object instead:

```
{
    ".content": 125,
    ".sidebar": 240
}
```

You can then iterate over the properties using a [`for in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Comment: +1 But maybe it should be `[{query: '.content', spacing: 125}, {query: '.sidebar', spacing: 240}]`, it's a little more expressive (and has order if that's needed)

Comment: @JuanMendes Of course! Do you have an example of how can I do this?

Comment: @chiefGui: Unless you need order, that's probably not necessary.  His code is an example; what are you having trouble with?

Comment: @SLaks Not necessary, just more expressive, naming the values instead of assuming that the key name is a query and that its value is a spacing value

Comment: @SLaks I'm not understanding how I can apply the "for in loop" to my case. I know this is the way, but technically speaking. By the way, I'm trying — hang on a second.

Comment: @chiefGui: The `for in` loop allows you to loop through all properties in an object. (for my example).  If you want to take Juan's approach, you would use a normal `for` loop to iterate through the objects in the array.

Comment: @SLaks Oh, I got it, SLaks — it is easy! But now I have to apply with my function, but for now everything is resolved. Thanks about your attention. Cheers!